# SSE intrinsics cause normal float operation to return -1.#INV

Tags: c++, sse, intrinsics

I am having a problem with a SSE method I am writing that performs audio processing. I have implemented a SSE random function based on Intel's paper here:

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/fast-random-number-generator-on-the-intel-pentiumr-4-processor/

I also have a method that is performing conversions from Float to S16 using SSE also, the conversion is performed quite simply as follows:

```
unsigned int Float_S16LE(float *data, const unsigned int samples, uint8_t *dest)
{
  int16_t *dst = (int16_t*)dest;
  const __m128 mul = _mm_set_ps1((float)INT16_MAX);
   __m128 rand;
  const uint32_t even = count & ~0x3;
  for(uint32_t i = 0; i < even; i += 4, data += 4, dst += 4)
  {
    /* random round to dither */
    FloatRand4(-0.5f, 0.5f, NULL, &rand);

    __m128 rmul = _mm_add_ps(mul, rand);
    __m128 in = _mm_mul_ps(_mm_load_ps(data),rmul);
    __m64 con = _mm_cvtps_pi16(in);

    memcpy(dst, &con, sizeof(int16_t) * 4);
  }
}
```

FloatRand4 is defined as follows:

```
static inline void FloatRand4(const float min, const float max, float result[4], __m128 *sseresult = NULL)
{
  const float delta  = (max - min) / 2.0f;
  const float factor = delta / (float)INT32_MAX;
  ...
}
```

If `sseresult != NULL` the `__m128` result is returned and `result` is unused. 
This performs perfectly on the first loop, but on the next loop `delta` becomes `-1.#INF` instead of `1.0`. If I comment out the line `__m64 con = _mm_cvtps_pi16(in);` the problem goes away.

I think that the FPU is getting into an unknown state or something.

Comment: _mm_cvtps_pi16 is a bad idea. Use a combination of _mm_cvtps_epi32, _mm_packs_epi32, and _mm_store_si128/_mm_storeu_si128 to convert 8 floats to 8 int16_t and your problem is gone!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mixing SSE Integer arithmetic and (regular) Floating point math. Can produce weird results because both are operating on the same registers. If you use:

```
_mm_empty()
```

the FPU is reset into a correct state. Microsoft has [Guidelines for When to Use EMMS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ays9ef83%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: isn't this just because of _mm_cvtps_pi16? I thought _mm_empty is MMX only. So I'd replace this, since _mm_empty is costly AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, the more correct solution is to do away with those FPU instructions and stick to SSE until completion, but this was the correct answer as it explained why it was occurring.

Answer (score 1):

- _mm_load_ps is not guaranteed to do an aligned load. float* data can be aligned to 4 bytes instead of 16 _ => _mm_loadu_ps
- memcpy will probably kill the advantages achieved with SSE, you should use a store command for __m64 but here again, take care of the alignment.
  If it's impossible to do an unaligned stream or store of an __m64, I'd either keep it inside an _m128i and do a masked write with _mm_maskmoveu_si128 or store those 8 bytes by hand.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bytwczae.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I should have stated that the alignment code is omitted from the sample posted, all data passed to this method is aligned.

Comment: How would you store the 8 bytes by hand?

Comment: I thought about an union with a uint8_t array[8] to copy manually. But there is always the problem, that such constructs (and memcpy) can cause 'store to load'. So transferring the __int64 (or two of them) into a 128bit register and doing _mm_maskmoveu_si128 or _mm_stream* respectively should be more efficient. Streaming avoids cache pollution with output, which may be of interest, since once written, you don't need it again immediately.

Comment: what about just extracting them using `_mm_extract_epi16`?

Comment: Yes, but if you intend to stick with __m64 for now, you can use _mm_extract_pi16 (SSE2) to extract word 0 - 3

Comment: Another approach is to keep two output registers, 2 x 4float converted to int32 with `_mm_cvtps_epi32` and then pack both into one vector using `_mm_packs_epi32`. Then you have 8 signed 16bit samples in a 128bit register to store/stream in one go.

Comment: I have opted for the `_mm_extract_epi16` method due to the fact that the buffer may not have enough values for 2 x 4float conversions and, __m64 intrinsics are not supported on x64 processors. Oh, and I can easily endian swap with `con = _mm_or_si128(_mm_slli_epi16(con, 8), _mm_srli_epi16(con, 8));`

Comment: OK, so i misunderstood your approach using `_mm_extract_epi16`. Extract does not a conversion, it just 'takes the bits'... so you must've applied a conversion to `con`, can you show me your modifications? I'm interesed in how you do that now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7138/discussion-between-geoffrey-and-sam)